# Saving a datetime from DatePicker as a string in custom format VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using a MS Datepicker to capture a date and need to save it to my SQLdb as a sting in the following format: yyyymmdd.  How do I convert the value from the DateTimePicker either in VB or in SQL?

example:
3/1/2018 should be 20180301 etc...

Comment: If it is a` DateTime`, you should save it as a `DateTime` so it acts like a `DateTime` and doesnt need the be converted when reading or writing.

Comment: I'm using a DB that was built years ago and don't have much flexibility to change it.  The original designer did it this way and I am trying to work within the bounds that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing dates as strings is always questionable, however, it you must

**Example**

```
Select convert(varchar(8),convert(date,'3/1/2018'),112)
```

or if 2012+

```
Select format(convert(date,'3/1/2018'),'yyyyMMdd')
```

**Returns**

```
20180301
```

Answer (score 0):

well C# is:

```
[DateTiemVar].ToString("yyyyMMdd") ;
```

I have to assume it is very siomilar in VB.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, suppose cDate is you field name

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(cDate,'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') as cDate;
```